# How to filter hstore where values are not null in a trigger?

Tags: postgresql, null, postgresql-11, hstore

The easiest way to explain the question is in the usage of an [audit trigger](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql).

However, on insert it saves all values, including null values. I want to filter out the null values in the `hstore(NEW.*)`. What is the simplest / fastest way to do this?

Source: https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql#L134

```
audit_row.row_data = hstore(NEW.*) - excluded_cols;
```

This obviously doesn't work but explains, hopefully, what the answer will look like.

```sql
audit_row.row_data = hstore(hstore(NEW.*) FILTER (WHERE value IS NOT NULL)) - excluded_cols;
```

Preference will go to answer that doesn't use an user created function, e.g. use only Postgres functions / operators.

This is for >= PostgreSQL 11.

I am looking for a solution with `hstore`, not `json` or `jsonb`. Alternative ways with `json` or `jsonb` may be included, but `hstore` is preferred.

Comment: Well, with jsonb you can use `jsonb_strip_nulls()`. What's wrong with using jsonb instead of hstore? The functions around jsonb are much more flexible and powerful anyways

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `hstore` is already in use. Switching to `jsonb` at this time isn't feasible. So we could convert using `hstore_to_jsonb()` and then `jsonb_strip_nulls()`. Is there a way to convert from `jsonb` to `hstore`? If that is possible, I would accept that answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it looks like we could do something like `select hstore(jsonb_each(jsonb_strip_nulls(some_hstore_data::jsonb))) from my_table;` do you foresee any issues?

Comment: The only possible other way to do it without going to `jsonb` and back is if there is a way to filter on a `set` e.g. filter `each(hstore)`, but not sure how to filter on a `set`.

Comment: Note: `select hstore(jsonb_each(jsonb_strip_nulls(some_hstore_data::jsonb))) from my_table;` doesn't work as it doesn't convert right. Maybe it could be modified to correctly convert.

Comment: It looks like something like this will work `(SELECT hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value)) FROM jsonb_each_text(jsonb_strip_nulls(some_hstore_data::jsonb) ))` and be in the correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With only built-in tools of Postgres and the additional module `hstore`, without involving `jsonb` (as requested):

```
audit_row.row_data = hstore(
   ARRAY (
      SELECT ARRAY[key, value]
      FROM   each(hstore(NEW.*) - excluded_cols)
      WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
      )
   );
```

One of the overloaded variants of the [`hstore()` functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) takes a two-dimensional array.

Alternatively, you could eliminate key names listed in `excluded_cols` in the `WHERE` clause (while processing unnested keys anyway):

```
audit_row.row_data = hstore(
   ARRAY (
      SELECT ARRAY[key, value]
      FROM   each(hstore(NEW.*))
      WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
      AND    key <> ANY (excluded_cols)
      )
   );
```

Might be a bit faster, not sure. Probably not much difference.

Also not sure how jsonb`and`jsonb_strip_nulls()` (suggested in comments) perform in comparison. Can you report back with a performance comparison?

Comment: Your suggestion is faster than converting to `jsonb` and back to `hstore` using SELECT. I haven't tested INSERT / TRIGGER, but would assume it's comparable.
`SELECT hstore( ARRAY ( SELECT ARRAY[key, value] FROM each(row_data) WHERE  value IS NOT NULL ) ) FROM audit.logged_actions ORDER BY event_id LIMIT 10000;` Is `Planning time: 0.172 ms Execution time: 679.332 ms`
and
`SELECT hstore( ARRAY ( SELECT ARRAY[key, value] FROM each(row_data) WHERE  value IS NOT NULL ) ) FROM audit.logged_actions ORDER BY event_id LIMIT 10000;` is `Planning time: 0.111 ms Execution time: 581.399 ms`

Comment: @thames: I see the same query twice. c/p hickup?

Comment: yeah c/p hickup. The query was `SELECT hstore( array_agg(key), array_agg(value)) FROM jsonb_each_text(jsonb_strip_nulls(row_data::jsonb) ) ) FROM audit.logged_actions ORDER BY event_id LIMIT 1000;` with `Planning time: 0.172 ms Execution time: 679.332 ms`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

- First, declare a new variable type `record`, example: `empty_row`
- Then, do as bellow:

```sql
EXECUTE format('select * from populate_record(null::%s.%s, '''')', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME) INTO empty_row;

audit_row.row_data = hstore(NEW.*) - empty_row - excluded_cols;
```

You can then reuse `empty_row` in different places in your function.

Comment: Results in an error. Doesn't seem to like the param as a type. Any suggestions? `[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Where: PL/pgSQL function if_modified_func() line 92 at EXECUTE`

Comment: I update the SQL to insert table name. Could you check it

Comment: `[42704] ERROR: type "logged_actions" does not exist.` You can also check it. The entire `audit.logged_actions` code/functions trigger is https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/audit-trigger/blob/master/audit.sql  after you run that script then call `SELECT audit.audit_table('myschema.my_table');` on the table you want to audit.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you use difference schema. I update to use TG_TABLE_SCHEMA to reflect it